# How to run Sudo code without password in mac

Tags: macos, terminal, sudo

I want to run "sudo rm ing /tmp/instruments_sock" in terminal. I am doing this through code using robotil jar. But I am not able to enter password. Is there any way that I run this command without asking for password in mac.!! **I want to remove password ONLY for this command.**

Comment: Well, I just google "mac sudo without password" and it gave me result. If you want I can copy paste steps here...

Comment: @AlexanderB. better not, the OP can google too - and this indicates that the OP didn't do any research. What's more - this is not a programming question, it's off-topic on StackOverflow and the OP should look in Superuser to see if somebody answered this question there already.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt, I agree, and basically my comment was a tip to go and to search something.

Comment: Most of the basic search results only show how to disable passwords for a user or a command. I think OP wants to have passwordless sudo for a certain command *with specific parameters*.

Comment: @jjs It's still not a programming question and is off-topic for StackOverflow

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt You're right. Superuser would be a better fit, even though OP wanted to do this through his java code.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to perform a single privileged task without a password, the best way is probably to use a [setuid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) binary.

In short, you make a tiny program that does what you want. You then give the program root privileges by setting its owner to root and enabling the setuid bit.

**A very important warning**: Don't just call `system("rm /tmp/something")` in your setuid binary! That is a classic security bug. Unclean environment variables (such as PATH) can hijack the command. There's a short introduction to the security problem in the wikipedia link above.

Instead of using system(), the easiest and safest way is to use the language's own file handling libraries. If you aren't 100% sure about what you are doing, avoid running shell commands from your binary.

Comment: Maybe point out that you set the `setuid` bit with `sudo chmod u+s YourScript` and you set its owner to root with `sudo chown root YourScript`.